# Языки программирования для создания приложений под Win и Debian

Tags: delphi, c++

Решил заняться не только вебом, но и созданием приложений под Win и Debian. Суть первой затеи, достаточно большой проект, особенно при учете почти полного незнания языков, на С++ могу в консоль "хеллоу ворлд" написать. От языка хотелось, чтобы не надо было мучиться с сетью и базой данных, пока планируется MySQL, пудумываю в сторону C++.

Хотелось бы получить совет, что сейчас является актуальным?

UPD.
Интересует даже в большей степени кроссплатформенность, то есть если есть смысл учить С++, то пусть С++, есть еще пару языков, видеть не видел, называется `BlitzMax`.

Comment: Загляните <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/33828/c-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-delphi">сюда</a>, тут уже много понаписано. Не к этому вопросу, для общей информации.

Comment: я вполне удовлетворён ответами, вопрос можно закрыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java, Qt, PyQt.
Java - проста и довольно быстра, не требует перекомпиляции при смене системы, но нужна виртуальная машина.
Qt - Библиотека под С++, требуется перекомпиляция.
PyQt - Python + Qt, не требуется компиляция (имплементируемый язык), самый простой из всех, но медленный и необходим интерпретатор (Py2Exe позволяет получить экзешник, а под linux интерпретатор ставится довольно просто)

Comment: а про QT можно подробнее, что это такое я уже в вики посмотрел, просто более подробно)

Answer (score 0):

Актуально Java и .NET (под mono в Linux). И то, и другое сильно сэкономит время по сравнению с C++. Есть ещё Adobe Air, но он менее приспособлен для чего-то большого, хотя и применим.

Comment: Adobe Air это вроде как про флеш, у меня цель не "колхоз") Java даже не знаю, держал когда то эмуль однй оч известной ММО он был на яве, я был не в восторге. хотя сейчас его перепилили на 10 раз и начали даже таки продавать. .NET, а что это вообще за зверь такое? дельфи видимо тоже пропадает, интересует кроссплатформеность без костылей.

Comment: "Глючные программы можно писать на любом языке."

Comment: Ilmirus полностью согласен.

Comment: А кто сказал, что Air - колхоз? И при чём тут костыли?